# What happens when a gold fish pond freezes?

Tags: fish, pond, temperature

I used to have a neighbor with a gold fish pond, and large (8 inch, 20 CM) or bigger gold fish (Koi?).  The pond was only about a foot deep and would often freeze over and/or freeze solid.  As I recall the fish seemed to survive for years of this freeze and thaw process.

What happens when a gold fish pond freezes?

Comment: Related [Is killing fish with iced water really humane?](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/10084)

Comment: Also related [Fish “coming back to life” after being frozen](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/1661/fish-coming-back-to-life-after-being-frozen)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is unlikely that a fish pond would freeze solid and have the gold fish survive.  As temperatures drop the fish enter a state of torpor (similar to hibernation). I could not find any reliable references supporting gold fish or koi surviving in a completely frozen pond.

The biggest risk to fish wintering over in frozen water is lack of oxygen. The layer of ice over the top of the pond causes the fish to suffocate. Solutions include a small heater in one corner of the pond that will keep a small area (not the whole pond) ice free and support gas exchange between the water and the air.

References

- [Goldfish: Your Happy Healthy Pet By Gregory Skomal, PhD](https://books.google.com/books?id=GJQkWknQz7UC&pg=PA78&dq=goldfish+pond+freeze+solid&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjg5Jzyxr_JAhVBRSYKHQMAD-AQ6AEINDAB#v=onepage&q=freeze&f=false)
- [Fish & Fishing  By Nicolae Sfetcu](https://books.google.com/books?id=4ZF_AwAAQBAJ&pg=PT216&dq=goldfish+pond+freeze+solid&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjg5Jzyxr_JAhVBRSYKHQMAD-AQ6AEILzAA#v=onepage&q=freeze%20solid&f=false)
- [HOW TO CARE FOR A GOLDFISH POND DURING THE WINTER MONTHS](http://animals.mom.me/care-goldfish-pond-during-winter-months-4409.html)
- [WHAT HAPPENS TO POND FISH IN WINTER?](http://fullserviceaquatics.com/pond-fish/what-happens-to-pond-fish-in-winter/)
- [Koi and Goldfish Pond Winter Care](http://extension.illinois.edu/gardenerscorner/issue_06/winter_04_10.cfm)

Comment: I had a little water feature that had frogs every summer. I had a little heater that would activate if the temperature got below 35 degrees F. That would allow a bit of ice on the surface, but kept an area ice free. I had frogs every year thanks to that little heater.